# Vue $emit in beforeDestroy

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, eventemitter

Vue - I want to track user changes on a page and send those updates if they navigate away. The basic idea is

```
//child
beforeDestroy: function() {
  var that = this;
  axios.post('gate/cart.php', userUpdates)
    .then(function(res) {
      if (res.data.success) {
        that.$emit('updateCart', res.data.cart);

//parent (App.vue)   
<router-view
  @updateCart="updateCart"

...
methods: {
  updateCart: function(newCart) {
    alert('caught');
    this.cart = newCart;
```

The dev tools show me the emit is emitted and the correct payload (res.data.cart) is sent, but the parent method isn't called. (That alert doesn't trigger.) I know the updateCart method in the parent is working, as another component uses it fine like this with a regular method:

```
addToCart: function() {
  var that = this;
  axios.post('gate/cart.php', this.dataToSend)
    .then(function(res) {
      if(res.data.success === true) {
        that.$emit('updateCart', res.data.cart)            
        that.$router.push({ path: '/product/' + that.product.id})
      }
```

If the ajax is working, I get a correct $emit, and the target method is ok, what lifecycle hook caveat is stopping me from executing the parent method? Do you know a better way to do this? (I want to check the success of the ajax call before updating the parent data.)

Comment: What I'm assuming is happening is that the child component is destroyed before the post request returns. So when the `$emit` is fired, the parent thinks the child is destroyed and is no longer listening for that child's event (that's conjecture I'm not sure). Would have to see where / how you are destroying the child to give advice on a better solution.

Comment: @thanksd Yup fair point. The beforeDestroy is called if the user clicks the browser back button or a menu link. The parent is the root App.vue, which passes the cart down to the child. I guess I need some way to persist a listener after the component is destroyed.